# Selecting a range of time-series data and performing data analysis

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a monitoring device that monitors temperature, pressure and humidity. With this data I get the date and time of measurement. The measurements occur every 5 seconds. I want to write a function that gives me the average and standard deviation of temp, press, and humidity within a particular range of dates and times. Ideally something like this...

```
def TempPressHumid(time_start, time_end, data_start, date_end, temp_data, press_data, humid_data)
```

so far i have this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('TM4CVC.csv', index_col = 0)

temp_data = df['Temperature']
temp_av = np.mean(temp_data)
temp_sd = np.std(temp_data)

humid_data = df['humidity']
humid_av = np.mean(humid_data)
humid_sd = np.std(humid_data)

press_data = df['pressure']
press_av = np.mean(press_data)
press_sd = np.std(press_data)
```

Is this possible?

Thanks,

Joey

Comment: look at the pandas docs about indexing and selecting data. http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#datetimeindex-partial-string-indexing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it. Slicing the df by time and date. You can change the function to only accept dates and then use the format 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss' to slice it if you want just a continuous range of datetimes instead of having to select the time and date every time.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random

def TempPressHumid(time_start, time_end, date_start, date_end, df):

    temp = df[date_start:date_end]
    temp = df.between_time(time_start,time_end)

    out = {'temp_avg':np.mean(temp['temp']),
    'temp_std':np.std(temp['temp']),
    'press_avg':np.mean(temp['press']),
    'press_std':np.std(temp['press']),
    'humid_avg':np.mean(temp['humid']),
    'humid_std':np.std(temp['humid'])}
    print out


df = pd.DataFrame({'temp':[random.randint(50, 80) for x in range(51841)],
    'press':[random.randint(20, 40) for x in range(51841)],
    'humid':[random.randint(20, 80) for x in range(51841)]}, 
    index = pd.date_range(start = '2014-01-01', end = '2014-01-04', freq = '5S'))

TempPressHumid(time_start = '01:00:00', time_end = '23:00:00', date_start = '2014-01-02', date_end = '2014-01-03', df = df)
```

This will get all the data between 2014-01-02 and 2014-01-03 for the times between 1am and 11pm.

Comment: Thanks for the response. 

Is it just a case of adding my data to this... for example

    df = pd.DataFrame({'temp': df['data_column'],
    'press':df['data_column'],
    'humid':df['data_column'], 
    index = pd.date_range(start = '2014-01-01', end = '2014-01-04', freq = '5S'))

I tried this and i get an error on the index syntax. =/

Comment: ignore above ..

I can't seem to index my own time and date. in the example you have given, you make your own date and time index... is it possible to use the time and date I already have?

Comment: It is definitely possible. Are they measure separately? So you would have a time column and a date columns, i.e. datetime.time() and datetime.date() format? Because it's a lot easier if they are combined into one format that has both date and time information. If they aren't formatted as datetime objects you can just combine them like strings and format it with `pd.to_datetime()`

Comment: Yeah, they are measured seperately. e.g. columns are in this order..... date, time, humid, temp, press .... i'm not sure how to link the function to the datetime index.... i've defined my column variables... but I have no idea how to combine and index the datetime column =/

Comment: Hopefully this should explain what I'm talking about. Just substitute in series in the 3rd line and then set this as the index. Once it is the index you can slice it. If you aren't familiar with the basics of pandas manipulation you should check out the documentation. time series: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html. Or more basic: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html
    `time = '12:00:00'`
    `date = '2014-12-30'`
    `datetime = pd.to_datetime(date+' '+time)`